# Can I install Xcode from the command line?

Tags: xcode, homebrew

Is it possible to install Xcode from the command line (on iOS)? I need it to create Appium tests, and because Appium is a booger to install, I'm trying to automate as much of the set-up as possible.

Comment: There is no command line on iOS (the apps are sandboxed); there is no Xcode installable on iOS.

Answer (score 0):

For me its a little bit hard to get your intention.

Do you want to install the Mac Xcode on an iOS device? No this is not possible?
-> no you cannot install the Xcode for Mac on iOS

Do you want to use an Terminal app on your iOS device to install Xcode for Mac on your Mac?

-> You can use [MAS](https://github.com/mas-cli/mas) and SSH into your Mac from your iOS device and execute the command.